# Custom Oh My Zsh theme: long prompts disappear / cut off

Tags: shell, themes, zsh, prompt

I had a go at making my own Oh My Zsh theme earlier. All is well, except when I type long lines in the prompt (any longer than the line seen below), the line disappears. The line re-appears if I resize the window, however.

Is there something in my theme that is causing this to happen?

[image]

If I type an additional character and then erase one, the cursor appears at the edge of the window.

[image]

You can [view the code for the theme here](https://github.com/OliverJAsh/SolarizedZSH). Here’s the bit I think we are concerned with:

```
# Build the prompt
PROMPT='
' # Newline
PROMPT+='${style_user}%n' # Username
PROMPT+='${style_chars}@' # @
PROMPT+='${style_host}%m' # Host
PROMPT+='${style_chars}: ' # :
PROMPT+='${style_path}%c ' # Working directory
PROMPT+='$(git_custom_status)' # Git details
PROMPT+='
' # Newline
PROMPT+='${style_chars}\$${RESET} '
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Incidentally, your link is broken, highlighting one of the issues with posting a link to code instead of code itself - any future viewers of your question can't get a full picture.

I think your problem is that the 'color' characters you use should be escaped in a pair of [`%{...%}`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshmisc/):

```
%{...%}
Include  a string as a literal escape sequence.  The string within the braces
should not change the cursor position.  Brace pairs can nest.
```

Using your latest [commit on github](https://github.com/OliverJAsh/SolarizedZSH/blob/master/solarized.zsh-theme), I don't see this issue - did you fix it? However, I'm seeing some issues with cursor placement and line-drawing, particularly with `TAB`. When pressing `TAB`, the cursor is moved up one line:

[image]
Pressed <kbd>TAB</kbd> here. 
[image]
Pressed <kbd>TAB</kbd> here. 
[image]

The `PROMPT` is being re-drawn 'up' one line every time. This is fixed by encapsulating the color codes within the `%{...%}`:

```
# Solarized Dark colour scheme
BOLD="%{$(tput bold)%}"
RESET="%{$(tput sgr0)%}"
SOLAR_YELLOW="%{$(tput setaf 136)%}"
SOLAR_ORANGE="%{$(tput setaf 166)%}"
SOLAR_RED="%{$(tput setaf 124)%}"
SOLAR_MAGENTA="%{$(tput setaf 125)%}"
SOLAR_VIOLET="%{$(tput setaf 61)%}"
SOLAR_BLUE="%{$(tput setaf 33)%}"
SOLAR_CYAN="%{$(tput setaf 37)%}"
SOLAR_GREEN="%{$(tput setaf 64)%}"
SOLAR_WHITE="%{$(tput setaf 254)%}"
```

I'm not 100% sure without the original `~/.zshrc`, but this should improve your prompt a little. :)

Apart from the orange, you can also use a terminal-based `Solarized` profile and the `zsh` `colors`, which *might* be more portable. I couldn't get the orange right without `tput`, though.

```
#autoload colors && colors
#SOLAR_YELLOW="%{$fg[yellow]%}"
#SOLAR_ORANGE="%{$(tput setaf 166)%}"
#SOLAR_RED="%{$fg[red]%}"
#SOLAR_MAGENTA="%{$fg[magenta]%}"
#SOLAR_VIOLET="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}"
#SOLAR_BLUE="%{$fg[blue]%}"
#SOLAR_CYAN="%{$fg[cyan]%}"
#SOLAR_GREEN="%{$fg[green]%}"
#SOLAR_WHITE="%{$fg[white]%}"
```

Comment: Do I need to escape other variables too, or is it just the colours? For example, I alias the colours to other variables such as: `style_path="${RESET}${SOLAR_GREEN}"`

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Provided it's escaped *somewhere*, you're good - I escaped at the earliest possible time (`SOLAR_<COLOR>`), so `style_path` will expand to `"%{$(tput sgr0)%}%{${tput setaf 64%}"`, with both variables escaped already - escaping the 'higher' variables won't *hurt*, but I don't think there's any advantage :)